# Does equal distribution of some members imply equal distribution of others

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a set U which is the Union of n subsets $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n$. Each $S_i$ is of the same size, and all of them contain distinct members. Now suppose that each member of U is colored either blue or green.

It is known that the blue members are equally distributed amongst all sets $S_i$. Is it safe to then conclude that the green members are then also equally distributed?

If these are infinite sets that you can show a bijection between each $S_i, S_j$ - does the result still hold the same as when these are finite sets?

Comment: I don't know what tag fits, but the set theory one does not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila no? But it’s a question about sets :(

Comment: What do you mean by "equally distributed"?

Comment: @ClementYung let’s say that equally distributed = there is a bijection for all of the blue elements in $S_i$ and $S_j$, for all i and j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the result is true if all the $S_i$'s are finite, but it is false if they are infinite.

Suppose $|S_i| = n$ for all $i$, where $n$ is some natural number. For each $i$, we write $S_i = B_i \sqcup G_i$, where $B_i$ is the set of all blue elements in $S_i$ and $G_i$ is the set of all green elements in $S_i$. Since $|G_i| = |S_i| - |B_i|$, if $|S_i| = |S_j|$ and $|B_i| = |B_j|$, then $|G_i| = |G_j|$.

If $|S_i|$ is infinite then it is a different story. We can do this as follows:  For each $i$, color $i$ elements of $S_i$ green, and all the rest blue. Then $|B_i| = |B_j|$ for all $i,j$ (why?), but clearly $|S_i|$'s are all different.

Comment: It seems like you are saying that a different number of elements can be colored green per $S_i$. I said in the OP that all $S_i$ are the same size. In the case of two infinite sets, aren’t they the same size iff there is a bijection between them? Would this not prevent a different number of green elements?

Comment: You are right that I'm saying that a different number of elements can be colored green per $S_i$. Let's say that, for instance, both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are countably infinite (so there is a bijection between them). If one element in $S_1$ is colored green and two elements in $S_2$ are colored green, then both $S_1$ and $S_2$ have countably infinite many elements colored blue. Hence there's still a bijection between the blue elements in $S_1$ and the blue elements in $S_2$.

Comment: I'm asserting that there is a bijection not just between the blue elements, but between all $S_i$ as a whole.

Comment: There are bijections between all $S_i$'s, as they are all countably infinite.

Comment: If there is a bijection between them, and a bijection over one of two types of elements therein, then shouldnt there be a bijection - and thus equal count - between the remaining elements?

Comment: That's only true for finite sets. For instance, there's a bijection between $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $\{3,4,5,\dots\}$, even though the second set of a proper subset of the first. The bijection is the map $f(n) = n + 2$.

Comment: I see. So rather than just a bijection I would need to show somehow that all of the elements “align” the same within the two sets? Or? Is there a term to describe the relationship between infinite sets like {1, 2, 3, …} and {a, b, c,  …, z, aa, ab, …} where the two sets are disjointed and have a bijection / equal count?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a term for what you want off the top of my head.